# Could meta http-equiv origin-trial be hacked content?

Tags: google-search-console, meta-tags, hacked-site, url-inspection-tool

Google alerted me that it found "malicious software" in my page.  Thinking that my site might be hacked, I went to Google Search Console's URL inspection and ran a live test on the reported URL.

The screenshot that Googlebot produced doesn't show anything out of the ordinary. The HTML source code shows the following addition:

`<meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="As0hBNJ8h++fNYlkq8cTye2qDLyom8NddByiVytXGGD0YVE+2CEuTCpqXMDxdhOMILKoaiaYifwEvCRlJ/9GcQ8AAAB8eyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2RvdWJsZWNsaWNrLm5ldDo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiV2ViVmlld1hSZXF1ZXN0ZWRXaXRoRGVwcmVjYXRpb24iLCJleHBpcnkiOjE3MTk1MzI3OTksImlzU3ViZG9tYWluIjp0cnVlfQ==" /><meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="AgRYsXo24ypxC89CJanC+JgEmraCCBebKl8ZmG7Tj5oJNx0cmH0NtNRZs3NB5ubhpbX/bIt7l2zJOSyO64NGmwMAAACCeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZXN5bmRpY2F0aW9uLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiV2ViVmlld1hSZXF1ZXN0ZWRXaXRoRGVwcmVjYXRpb24iLCJleHBpcnkiOjE3MTk1MzI3OTksImlzU3ViZG9tYWluIjp0cnVlfQ==" /><meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="A/ERL66fN363FkXxgDc6F1+ucRUkAhjEca9W3la6xaLnD2Y1lABsqmdaJmPNaUKPKVBRpyMKEhXYl7rSvrQw+AkAAACNeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2RvdWJsZWNsaWNrLm5ldDo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiRmxlZGdlQmlkZGluZ0FuZEF1Y3Rpb25TZXJ2ZXIiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE3MTkzNTk5OTksImlzU3ViZG9tYWluIjp0cnVlLCJpc1RoaXJkUGFydHkiOnRydWV9" /><meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="A6OdGH3fVf4eKRDbXb4thXA4InNqDJDRhZ8U533U/roYjp4Yau0T3YSuc63vmAs/8ga1cD0E3A7LEq6AXk1uXgsAAACTeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZXN5bmRpY2F0aW9uLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiRmxlZGdlQmlkZGluZ0FuZEF1Y3Rpb25TZXJ2ZXIiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE3MTkzNTk5OTksImlzU3ViZG9tYWluIjp0cnVlLCJpc1RoaXJkUGFydHkiOnRydWV9" />`

Does anybody know what this could be?  A Google search seems to indicate that it is somehow associated with beta versions of the Chrome browser.  I don't see what hackers could gain by adding this to my pages.  I suspect that this is much more likely to be something added to the DOM by Googlebot as it crawls the page.

Is there any reason to think that my site is hacked because this data is showing up in my pages in URL inspection?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't add this to your website, then somebody else did...and it's not Googlebot. Origin trials are something you intentionally register for to test new Chrome features.

Here's a link to [currently active origin trials](https://developer.chrome.com/origintrials/#/trials/active), perhaps there's some confusion.